# How to print project related comments in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I need to print my comments table comments related to each project in my Laravel application. I am using domPDF for my PDF class. This is my PDF print controller:

```
class pdfController extends Controller
{
    public function getPDFFF($id){
        $comments = Comment::project($id)->get(); //line 14
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdf.out',['comments'=>$comments]);
        return $pdf->stream('comment.pdf');
    }
    //
}
```

This is my comments table structure:

```
id  comments  project_id
 1    asc        1
 2    fgt        5
 3    gft        2
```

But with this controller I get the following error message:

> ErrorException in pdfController.php line 14: Non-static method App\Comment::project() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `project_id` from comments table to get comments for some project:

```
$comments = Comment::where('project_id',$id)->get();
```